# How can I self reference the table I'm working on in a dbt Project?

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I'm looking to self-reference the table I'm working on within a model file in the config block to alias the table name. Right now, I'm naming dynamically naming the alias using a Python file for loop but would prefer if the model file recognized and designated the table name in itself.

```
{{ config(
    alias=model.table ### this.name? not sure what syntax to use here ###
) }}

select *

from {{ source('aceso', 'aceso_accountlookup') }}

{% if is_incremental() %}

    where _FIVETRAN_SYNCED > (select max(_FIVETRAN_SYNCED) from {{ this }} )

{% endif %}
```

Currently I have no idea the format of syntax required to get dbt to understand what I want it to do

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What name do you want to use for the alias? The name of the model file? Something else?

Comment: If the model is working on the aceso_accountlookup table in the above example, I would like to use this name for the alias without statically writing the table name if that makes sense.

Comment: why don't you just name the model `aceso_accountlookup.sql`?

Comment: There are 4 subsections of this model project of various transformations so unfortunately requires unique model names due to the ref function.

Answer (score 0):

dbt currently has a strong one-database-object-per-model association, so what you seem to be trying to describe (based on reading your answers to @tconbeer's questions in the comments) isn't really possible without something hacky like you're already doing.

There is a GitHub Discussion around making it possible for dbt to generate multiple objects from a single model [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/discussions/5101) that you may wish to contribute to.